# SIGSEGV singal 11, java.lang.IllegalStateException: Parcel has been finalized

Tags: java, android

My app works on android kitkat and android 7.0. however, the app crashes randomly stating "illegalstateexception: parcel has been finalized" on android Lollipop 5.0.2.

Sometimes the same type of crash occurs with textview.settext() method.

any idea, if this behavior is valid on 5.0.2?

Here is the logcat dump.

```
    Process: de.bla.test, PID: 11766
                                                       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Parcel has been finalized!
                                                           at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
                                                           at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
                                                           at android.app.usage.IUsageStatsManager$Stub$Proxy.queryEvents(IUsageStatsManager.java:263)
                                                           at android.app.usage.UsageStatsManager.queryEvents(UsageStatsManager.java:196)
                                                           at de.bla.test.mainActivity$2.run(Unknown Source)
                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    12-19 11:01:55.238 271-271/? I/DEBUG: pid: 11766, tid: 14081, name: Thread-1694  >>> de.bla.test <<<
    12-19 11:01:55.938 1065-1439/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{3f4cc3e5 u0 de.bla.test/de.bla.test.mainActivity}
    12-19 11:01:55.948 1065-1080/? I/WindowState: WIN DEATH: Window{5d9d744 u0 de.bla.test}
    12-19 11:01:55.968 1065-1602/? I/ActivityManager: Process de.bla.test (pid 11766)(adj 1) has died(114,897)
    12-19 11:01:55.968 1065-1602/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service de.bla.test/.txtOverlay in 1000ms
    12-19 11:01:55.968 1065-1602/? W/ActivityManager: Scheduling restart of crashed service de.bla.test/.AccessibilityService in 10999ms
    12-19 11:01:56.048 1065-1065/? D/CrashAnrDetector: Build: samsung/gt510ltexx/gt510lte:5.0.2/LRX22G/T555XXU1AOJ1:user/release-keys
                                                       Hardware: msm8916
                                                       Revision: 8
                                                       Bootloader: T555XXU1AOJ1
                                                       Radio: unknown
                                                       Kernel: Linux version 3.10.49-5975984 (dpi@SWHD8906) (gcc version 4.8 (GCC) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Oct 8 17:23:40 KST 2015

                                                       *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
                                                       Build fingerprint: 'samsung/gt510ltexx/gt510lte:5.0.2/LRX22G/T555XXU1AOJ1:user/release-keys'
                                                       Revision: '8'
                                                       ABI: 'arm'
                                                       pid: 11766, tid: 14081, name: Thread-1694  >>> de.bla.test <<<
                                                       signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x10
                                                           r0 00000000  r1 fffffffe  r2 00000000  r3 00000000
                                                           r4 a295d6ec  r5 fffffffe  r6 00000000  r7 22ccba80
                                                           r8 fffffffe  r9 b88f3100  sl 720b5898  fp 22ccba80
                                                           ip b6edebf8  sp a295d6b0  lr b6e7628d  pc b6c0b614  cpsr 600f0030
                                                           d0  22d0a54022d0a4e0  d1  22d0a64022d0a5a6
                                                           d2  00000000000000d0  d3  0000000000000022
                                                           d4  ffffffffffff0000  d5  0000000000000001
                                                           d6  ffffffffffff0000  d7  40000000ffffffff
                                                           d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
                                                           d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
                                                           d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
                                                           d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
                                                           d16 0000000000000000  d17 ffffffffffffffff
                                                           d18 0001000100010001  d19 0001000100010001
                                                           d20 0000000000000001  d21 0000000000000000
                                                           d22 0000000000000000  d23 0000000000000000
                                                           d24 0000000000000000  d25 0000000000000000
                                                           d26 0002000200020001  d27 0002000200020002
                                                           d28 0080008000800080  d29 0080008000800080
                                                           d30 0800080008000800  d31 0800080008000800
                                                           scr 80000010

                                                       backtrace:
                                                           #00 pc 00020614  /system/lib/libbinder.so (int android::Parcel::writeAligned<int>(int)+3)
                                                           #01 pc 00083289  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
                                                           #02 pc 000b23bf  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat

                                                       stack:
                                                                a295d630  b6f69de4  
                                                                a295d634  00000001  
                                                                a295d638  00000030  
                                                                a295d63c  b51144dc  /system/lib/libart.so
                                                                a295d640  b5113d74  /system/lib/libart.so
                                                                a295d644  b5113d4c  /system/lib/libart.so
                                                                a295d648  b51144dc  /system/lib/libart.so
                                                                a295d64c  b5113c94  /system/lib/libart.so
                                                                a295d650  b5113ca8  /system/lib/libart.so
                                                                a295d654  a295d688  [stack:14081]
                                                                a295d658  22c8b610  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (deleted)
                                                                a295d65c  b51144dc  /system/lib/libart.so
                                                                a295d660  00000000  
                                                                a295d664  b5113d4c  /system/lib/libart.so
                                                                a295d668  b51144dc  /system/lib/libart.so
                                                                a295d66c  00550000  
                                                                a295d670  00430000  
                                                                a295d674  00550000  
                                                                a295d678  a295d688  [stack:14081]
                                                                a295d67c  b51144dc  /system/lib/libart.so
                                                                a295d680  00000001  
                                                                a295d684  efde5f73  
                                                                a295d688  00430000  
                                                                a295d68c  b88f3100  [heap]
                                                                a295d690  00000001  
                                                                a295d694  00000000  
                                                                a295d698  00430000  
                                                                a295d69c  00550000  
                                                                a295d6a0  b88f3100  [heap]
                                                                a295d6a4  00430000  
                                                                a295d6a8  22ccba80  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (deleted)
                                                                a295d6ac  0000032b  
                                                           #00  a295d6b0  00000000  
                                                                a295d6b4  a295d6ec  [stack:14081]
                                                                a295d6b8  b84e17f0  [heap]
                                                                a295d6bc  b6e7628d  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
                                                           #01  a295d6c0  0000032b  
                                                                a295d6c4  00000000  
                                                                a295d6c8  00000000  
                                                                a295d6cc  761583c1  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat
                                                           #02  a295d6d0  fffffffe  
                                                                a295d6d4  00000000  
                                                                a295d6d8  00000002  
                                                                a295d6dc  720b2020  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.art
                                                                a295d6e0  720b3048  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.art
                                                                a295d6e4  00000000  
                                                                a295d6e8  00000001  
                                                                a295d6ec  720b2020  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.art
                                                                a295d6f0  00000000  
                                                                a295d6f4  00000000  
                                                                a295d6f8  00000000  
                                                                a295d6fc  22ccba80  /dev/ashmem/dalvik-main space (deleted)
                                                                a295d700  fffffffe  
                                                                a295d704  720b5898  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework
    12-19 11:01:56.048 1065-1065/? D/CrashAnrDetector: processName:de.bla.test
    12-19 11:01:56.058 1065-1065/? D/CrashAnrDetector: broadcastEvent : de.bla.test SYSTEM_TOMBSTONE
```

Comment: Are you reading information using Cursors, somewhere?

Comment: No, no cursors involved.